# SyntaxError: EOF while reading a line

Tags: python

So I've recently been trying to run a code on Python. Basically, it's a simple calculator.
But whenever I run it, after putting in the type of calculation (E.g. - , +), I get the error message: 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'.
Here's the line of code:

```
  while True:
a = float(input("What is your first number?"))
b = float(input("What is your second number?"))
c = input("What type of calculation is it?")
if c == '+':
  print('Now calculating'), a
  print('add', b)
  print(a + b)
elif c == '-':
  print('Now calculating', a)
  print('take away', b)
  print(a - b)
elif c == '/':
  print('Now calculating', a)
  print('divided by', b)
  print(a / b)
elif c == '*':
  print('Now calculating', a)
  print('multiply',b)
  print(a * b)
elif c == '**':
  print('Now calculating', a)
  print('to the power of', b)
  print(a ** b)
else:
  print("Calculation is not possible")
```

Anyone know why?
Also, put it in Laymen's terms because I'm kinda new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = input("What type of calculation is it?")
```

If you're using Python 2.7, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

```
c = raw_input("What type of calculation is it?")
```

According to `help(input)`, input in 2.7 is "Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`". Meaning, if the user types "+", the interpreter attempts to evaluate the string "+" as a Python expression. The interpreter is surprised to reach the end of the string without having formed a full valid expression, so it tells you "unexpected EOF (end of file)"

Comment: (And also in Python 2 `print` isn't a function and your printing of tuples will give odd output...)

Comment: When i try to run the code now I get:
EOFError: EOF when reading a line. help anyone?

Comment: It may be worthwhile to post a new question about that error. It could be caused by something unrelated to this post.